# Retrieving all from all rows from jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I've a datatable, which is created dynamically. Number of rows differs from user to user. Some may create 2 rows, some may create 3 etc. For example, the table may look like this:

```
|     Category      |   User   |
|      Manager      |  Krishna |
| Assistant Manager |  Guru    |
```

They will be selected from a select dropdown. This is how I tried to retrieve all the data from the table when the submit button is clicked:

```
var noofrows = tabResources.data().count();
var data = tabResources.rows(0).data();
                alert(data);
```

In the alert, I get `[object, object]`. But, I don't know how to retrieve each value. How can I do that? This is the table:

```
tabResources = $("#tabResources").DataTable({
                "sDom":"t",
                ajax:{
                    "url":"../api/projectapi.php?action=getresourcebyprojectid",
                    "type":"GET",
                    "data":{"projectid": <?php echo $_GET ["projectid"]?>}
                },
                "destroy":true,
                "ordering":false,
                "columns":[

                           {"title":"Resource Category", "data":"resourcecategoryid","render":function(data, type, row){
                               return '<select class="form-control selectresourcecategoryid" name="resourcecategoryid[]" valueid=' + data + '></select>';
                            }},
                            {"title":"User", "data":"userid","render":function(data, type, row){
                                   return '<select class="form-control selectuserid" name="userid[]" valueid=' + data + '></select>';
                                }},
                                {"orderable":false, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                                    return '<a href="javascript:void(0)"  class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-remove">Remove</a>';               
                                    } 
                                }
                ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the snippet, does this solve your problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var data = [
       ['name1', 'position1', 'office1', 15],
       ['name2', 'position2', 'office2', 30]
    ];
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      data: data,
      columns: [
        {
          title: "Name"
        },{
          title: "Position"
        },{
          title: "Office"
        }
      ]
    });
 
    var data = table.data();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      console.log(data[i]);
    }
      
} );
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
```